# How can i get the Session Settings , Session Timeout from Salesforce using Rest call?

Tags: salesforce

Is there a Rest Api call I can make to get the Session Timeout Value under Session Settings in Salesforce ?

Answer (score 0):

Org-level defaults are available in metadata API but it's SOAP based, you'd need to create "package.xml" file and retrieve https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm and search for `sessionTimeout`

And you might need an admin account to do it, mortals typically can't view setup and use such development APIs.

It's not terribly useful anyway because every profile can override the default (Profile -> Session Settings, Profile -> Password Policies). You want [ProfileSessionSetting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilesessionsetting.htm).

Metadata API might be the only way, I don't see anything that would suggest REST API or Tooling API expose this object. I don't see it in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm

Consider asking on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too?